# PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: java, android, system, panic

Yesterday I got a problem with my Android Studio. I'm just new in the programming field. I installed Android Studio in November 2019. Yesterday I got this error after updating

PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

I've read the same themes on this forum, but it didn't help me. I wrote ANDROID_SDR_ROOT in the "Environment variables" an SDK address. I also re-installed the android studio 2 times, but I didn't help too.

My PC: Intel Core i5 7200U, RAM 16GB, Win10, API 29, SDK 26

What should I do more? I want to learn more about Android but I can't do this second day in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with re-installing the Android Studio in another user.

My first user was written in non-ASCII characters. I re-installed in a new AppData from new user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the same system path for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME